# sql: filter on created column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a very simple sql table:

```
 id | step
----+------
  1 |    1
  2 |    2
  3 |    3
```

I'm trying to create a new column based on a simple operation and filter on that new column. The newly created table before the filter should look like this:

```
 id | step | new
----+------+-----
  1 |    1 |  10
  2 |    2 |  20
  3 |    3 |  30
```

I thought the following query should work:

```
select id, step, step*10 as new from event where new = 20
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR:  column "new" does not exist

Comment: Try select id, step, step*10 as new from event where step*10 = 20 since the where clause will not recognize the field alias.

Comment: Since your example is trivial, if your table is large, a function-based index will help you a lot.  I realize this is off-topic, but hopefully helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` is processed before `select` which is why calculated column `new` is unknown at that time. Use `step*10=20` instead.

Or use a sub-query and filter with the alias.

```
select * 
from (select id, step, jsonb_array_elements(payload::jsonb->'sample_id') as new 
      from event 
     ) e
where new = --somevalue
```

Comment: `new` is actually a much more complex operation (`jsonb_array_elements(payload::jsonb->'sample_id')`). Is there an easier way to do this without repeating the operation code?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like subqueries, you can use a lateral join:

```
with event as (
      select 1 as id, 2 as step
     )
select e.id, e.step, v.new
from event e cross join lateral
     (values (e.step * 10)) v(new)
where v.new = 20;
```

This is convenient when you have multiple expressions that depend on each other.  Rather than nesting subqueries or CTEs, you can just add them to the `FROM` clause.